# Moving all files in a directory ignoring the file extension

Tags: command-line, bash, mac

I have a directory with multiple images in a different file types (svg, png, jpeg, jpg and gif), I also have a txt file which holds many names of images, but without the file extension, for ex:

```
1664
2048
3m
5asec
6play
7_eleven
7_up
aba_pagum
abc
abouelafia
absolut
accor_hotels
acdc
ace
acer
actimel
```

I want to loop throgh the file and find the image in the directory without the extension and move it to a new folder. For ex:

```
1664 -> move 1664.svg to the new folder
2048 -> move 2048.gif to the new folder
```

And so on..

What I have managed to come up with is this: (move.sh)

```
# Create a directory
mkdir 01_img_exists

# Read text file with image names
cat image_names.txt | while read i; do
    # Move images to folder
   mv ./${i} ./01_img_exists
done
```

How can I move the files ignoring the extension?

Comment: a lazy was is krusader file manager, edit, select group, pulldown images option. and if it misses an extension, do again using *sfv for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

```
mkdir -p 01_img_exists

while read i
  do
    echo mv ./"$i."* ./01_img_exists/
  done < image_names.txt
```

Try the above then remove `echo` when satisfied with the results to do the actual moving.

- `mkdir -p` will create the directory if it doesn't exist.
- `"$i."*` will match all names in the `image_names.txt` file plus anything after the first `.` i.e. any extension.
- `< image_names.txt` specifies the input file to be read.

You can omit the leading `./` and it will work fine.

**Notice:**

There is a limit on the number of files passed to `mv` as arguments in one single command. This limit is called `ARG_MAX`. There is a little chance that you might encounter this limit. It is, however, unlikely in your case given the limited number of extensions per the same filename. If you encounter that limit by any chance, try the code below instead.

```
mkdir -p 01_img_exists

while read i
  do
  for f in "$i."*
    do
      echo mv "$f" 01_img_exists/
    done
  done < image_names.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the specified answer! I also learned how to do it and also learned the 'echo' part trick :) Thanks!